# Mathematica Not Saving Variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I try to perform this nested loop but it is not working. It's not saving the result in each stage. But if I replace listInitial with Print[ ] I observer that all changes are made.

Any suggestions??

```
For[b = 1, b < 4, b = b + 1,
 For[a = 1, a < 4, a = a + 1,
  For[x = 1, x < 4, x = x + 1,
   For[z = 1, z < 4, z = z + 1, listInitial = 
    If[Random[] > psurvival, 
      ReplacePart[
       InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {b, a, x, z} -> 
        InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3][[b]][[a]][[x]][[z]] - 1], 
      InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {b, a, x, z} -> 
       InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3][[b]][[a]][[x]][[z]]]]]]]

listInitial // TableForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I found this solution:
I think it's the easier one and it's working.

```
SetAttributes[myFunction, Listable]
myFunction[x_] := 
 If[Random[] > psurvival, If [x - 1 < 0 , x , x - 1], x]
 myFunction[InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3]] // TableForm
```

Comment: Are you sure? It does something completely different from what you seemed to do in your question. For instance, there you call Random[] 64 times, and here only 1 time.

Comment: why only one? For every x the function is called. So I think is called 64 times again! From the results that's what I found at least!

Comment: This was assuming that your new function listing replaced your entire previous listing, which you implied.

Comment: x is called, but Random[] isn't. In your earlier version, Random[] can be different for different elements in your tensor. In your new version, it is the same for every element. Try my version above and see how it goes.

Comment: Nop. You are wrong. I tested 3-4 times and random is different for each element! Because myFunction is called for each element and some elements are reduced by one some other not! So number cannot be the same!

Comment: Oh, the Listable attribute. Right. No need to shout, dude. But test my version for timing relative to yous.

Comment: And in your other question under another user name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553717/for-loop-to-change-the-values-of-a-four-dimensional-table, you admit that your version changes all elements of the list the same way. So see my answer to that question, when it comes.

Comment: Mate sorry if I was rude. I didn't posted any other question here regarding mathematica. I posted this to help a friend. As you can see from my other questions I am a programmer but I also like maths. Sorry again if I was rude. Thanks for your answer too. And the time that you spent but this is working exactly as it supposed to work. I found this solution as an example in a book.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you expect `ReplacePart` to change `InitialMatrix`. It does not. It does change a nameless copy of `InitialMatrix` and returns this as a result, which is then assigned to `listInitial`. The latter is overwritten with a new value every loop iteration, so in the end it only contains the result of the *last* replacement. With all variables equal to 3 at that point, the last replacement looks like:

```
InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {3, 3, 3, 3}->InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3][[3]][[3]][[3]][[3]]]
```

which effectively doesn't do anything. The end result is `listInitial` containing what you started with.

**Edit**
I just spotted that the second argument of your If statement clearly is formatted for a second instance of `ReplacePart`, which is missing here,

Answer (score 3):

I question whether you need a four-fold nested For loop at all. If I understand your code correctly, you have a 3*3*3*3 tensor, and you want to decrement the initial value of each element by 1 if some random number is above some threshold. I am assuming that `InitialMatrix` is a function you have already properly defined, rather than being some object.

Surely this will work:

```
InitialMatrix[3,3,3,3] + Table[If[RandomReal[]>psurvival,-1,0],{3},{3},{3},{3} ]
```

In version 8, you can replace the `Table` function with

```
-RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1-psurvival], {3,3,3,3}]
```

If the tensor is always n*n*n*n, then you could write a little function:

```
decrementInitial[n_Integer?Positive,p_?Positive]/; p<=1. :=
InitialMatrix[n,n,n,n] + Table[If[RandomReal[]>p,-1,0],{n},{n},{n},{n} ]
```

If you are wanting to rewrite the initial matrix because you are wanting to iterate the survival function in a number of steps, then something like this using a pure function would be suitable (for version 8).

```
survivalFn[n_Integer?Positive,p_?Positive,steps_Integer?Positive]/; p<=1. :=
Nest[# + RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1-p], {n,n,n,n}]& , 
InitialMatrix[n,n,n,n], steps]
```

Or for versions prior to 8:

```
survivalFn[n_Integer?Positive,p_?Positive,steps_Integer?Positive]/; p<=1. :=
Nest[# - Table[If[RandomReal[]>p,-1,0],{n},{n},{n},{n} ]& , 
InitialMatrix[n,n,n,n], steps]
```

Something about the way you asked the question suggested to me that this was what you were trying to do ultimately.

***Additional material on request from user825366***

I'm not sure exactly what you want to know about the function but let's go through a few things. First the `BernoulliDistribution` function. The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BernoulliDistribution.html) says:

> Bernoulli distribution gives value x=1 with probability p, and x=0 with probability 1-p.

You want 0 with probability `psurvival` and -1 with probability `1-psurvival`, so essentially you have `-BernoulliDistribution[1-psurvival]`.

Next, the `Nest` function (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html)). That takes some function, applies it to the starting value (in this case `InitialMatrix[3,3,3,3]`), then applies it again to whatever the result from that first iteration was, and iterates for the appropriate number of steps.

Within the definition of the function to be Nested, it is common to use **pure functions**. You should read [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) in the documentation, and [this one too](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to assign the result to initialMatrix to see the result of the ReplacePart, as in

```
In[27]:= A={1 ,2 };
A=ReplacePart[A,1->99];
A

Out[29]= {99,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to solve this

```
InitialTable[x_, y_, z_, w_] := 

  MapAt[g, 
   ReplacePart[
    InitialMatrix[x, y, z, w] + 
     ReplacePart[
      Table[If[RandomReal[] > psurvival2, -1, 0], {x}, {y}, {z}, {w}], 
     {{_, _, 1, _} -> 0, {_, _, 2, _} -> 0}],  
   {{_, _, 1, 2} -> 0, {_, _, 1, 3} -> 0}], 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, x}, {j, y}, {k, z}, {l, w}], 3]];

g[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, x];
```