# For loop to change the values of a four dimensional table

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like your help on something,

I have a Table:

```
InitialMatrix[x_, y_, age_, disease_] :=

  ReplacePart[Table[Floor[Divide[dogpopulation/cellsno,9]], {x}, {y}, {age}, {disease}], 
{{_, _, 1, _} ->  0, {_, _, 3, _} -> 6}];
```

I was trying to set up a condition to change all the values inside the table to sumthing else, according to a value, I tried:

```
listInitial={};

For[a = 1, a < 4, a++,

 For[b = 1, b < 4, b++,

  For[x = 1, x < 4, x = x + 1,

   For[z = 1, z < 4, z = z + 1,

 listInitial =

 If[Random[] > psurvival, 

      ReplacePart[ InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {a, b, x, z} -> 
        InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3][[a]][[b]][[x]][[z]] - 1], 

      InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {a, b, x, z} -> 
       InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3][[a]][[b]][[x]][[z]]]]]]]
```

but it only changes the last part of my table, finally I decided to use the following code instead of the for loop,

```
SetAttributes[myFunction, Listable]

myFunction[x_] := 
 If[Random[] > psurvival, If [x - 1 < 0 , x , x - 1], x]

 myFunction[InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3]] // TableForm
```

but now I want to change specific parts inside the table, for example I want all the part 
`{__,__,3,_}` to change I tried to choose the range with `MapAt` but again I think I need to do a loop, and I cannot, can any one please help me?

```
For[x = 1, x < 4, x++,
  listab[MapAt[f, InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], {x, 3, 3}]//TableForm]]
```

Comment: This is already posted (apparently by another user) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542038/mathematica-not-saving-variable. I suggest the user try my answer to that question. Well, not the same question, but now the user realises why his own answer didn't give him what he wants.

Comment: yeah... This is true.. the other user is a friend of mine who was trying to help me with my problem, he is the one who replied to you, but since I wasn't happy with my result I decided to post again with my account. I try what you said before but I am a little bit confused with one of your suggestions

Comment: Ok, fair enough. It would help to know what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the documentation for MapAt, you will see that you can address multiple elements at various depths of your tensor, using various settings of the third argument. Note also the use of Flatten's second argument. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
MapAt[g, InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], 
Flatten[Table[{i, j, 3, k}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}], 2]]
```

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html

Since this seems to be your second attempt to ask a question involving a really complicated For loop, may I just emphasise that you **almost never need a For or Do loop** in Mathematica in the circumstances where you would use one in, say, Fortran or C. Certainly not for most construction of lists. Table works. So do things like Listable functions (which I know you know) and commands like NestList, FoldList and Array.

You will probably also find this tutorial useful.
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SelectingPartsOfExpressionsWithFunctions.html

Comment: Thank you very much,
I am also interested on that code
 survivalFn[n_Integer?Positive,p_?Positive,steps_Integer?Positive]]/; p<=1. :=
Nest[# + RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1-p], {n,n,n,n}]& , 
InitialMatrix[n,n,n,n], steps]
you wrote that before in another post but I didn't understand what this code really do

Comment: If I want to add some values in this new matrix that we have here 
MapAt[g, InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3], 
Flatten[Table[{i, j, 3, k}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}], 2]]
for example at g[6] I want to have a condition and if this condition is true then I want to add some values in at this specific element.. for now I have done it like :
New[x_, y_, z_, w_] := 
  InitialMatrix[x, y, z, w] + 
   ReplacePart[
    Table[If[RandomReal[] > psurvival, -1, 
      0], {x}, {y}, {z}, {w}], {{_, _, 1, _} -> 0, {_, _, 2, _} -> 
      0}];
you suggested that before, but which method is better?

Comment: I can't answer either of these questions in 600 characters so I will post an additional answer on the other question in answer to your first comment. I will answer the second comment as an additional answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code as an answer, I am not sure whether is the best solution or not, but it works!!

```
InitialTable[x_, y_, z_, w_] := 

  MapAt[g,ReplacePart[
   InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3] + 
    ReplacePart[
     Table[If[RandomReal[] > psurvival, -1, 
       0], {3}, {3}, {3}, {3}], {{_, _, 1, _} -> 0, {_, _, 2, _} -> 
       0}], {{_, _, 1, 2} -> 0, {_, _, 1, 3} -> 0}], 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, 3, l}, {i, x}, {j, y}, {l, w}], 2]];

g[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, x];
```

Comment: What your code does is set the elements {_,_,1,2} and {_,_,1,3} of the original matrix to zero in all cases: it happens outside the second ReplacePart function. Is this really what you want? You could use the Floor function for this instead. You then decrement the other variables according to a Bernoulli distributed function (see my other answer to the other question). Your MapAt function just enforces that population never goes negative. You could use the Ceiling function instead for this (Ceiling[#,0]&). In any case, this isn't the question you originally asked.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try what you said :)

Comment: @Verbeia Can you please check out my other question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558067/change-two-different-parts-in-a-table-according-to-the-same-random-value) I think you are the only one who may help me... I am trying all day(today and yesterday) to figure it out but I can't!! Please help me if you can