# Change two different parts in a table according to the same random value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to change 2 different rows in my table according to one random variable each time, For example I want if a random number>0.5 then to change one row with the value in it +1 and the other row with its value -1, otherwise do nothing. I tried the following code but I am confused, Can anyone please help me?

```
InitialMatrix[3, 3, 3, 3] + 
  MapAt[f, MapAt[g, Table[0, {3}, {3}, {3}, {3}],

    Flatten[Table[{i, j, 1, k}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}], 2]], 
   Flatten[Table[{i, j, 2, k}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}], 2]] // TableForm

f[x_] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.5, g[x] = If[x > 0, x - 1, x]; 
  If[g[x] > 0, x + 1, x], x]
```

Thank you very much!!

**Edit: Changed requirements**

I have a four dimensional table and I want to change the values in it with respect to each other.

My table is

```
InitialMatrix[x_, y_, age_, disease_] :=

  ReplacePart[ Table[Floor[Divide[dogpopulation/cellsno,  9]], 
    {x}, {y}, {age},  {disease}], {{_, _, 1, _} ->   0, {_, _, 3, _} -> 6}];
```

I am trying to change the first 2 rows in each subtmatrix according to one random variable each time.

For example I want if a random number>0.4 then to change the first element in the first row with its value +1 and the first element of the second row with its value minus 1 otherwise leave the value as it is.

I want to check every element in the first row with a different random number and if the condition is true then to change both 1 and second row. Can I do something like that?

Comment: This feels very much like your last question.

Comment: What is `InitialMatrix`?

Comment: It is my own Table nothing on mathematica, it is just a name that I gave to it

Comment: @noni Your edit changed the meaning of the question completely, and renders my answer unusable. In the future, please leave the original question unchanged and add an **Edit** section at the end, so future readers can understand why some answers are there

Comment: @noni - Is there any reason why you typed Divide[dogpopulation/cellsno,  9] rather than (dogpopulation/cellsno)/9?

Comment: Also, your code replaces parts with particular (fixed) values. Your question suggests that instead you want to increment/decrement them. Which is it?

Comment: @belisarius I am really sorry about that I will try to write the first question as it was or write a comment about it. I didn't know that this was wrong, I am really sorry!!

Comment: @noni I recovered the old question from the edit history and edited the question

Comment: @belisarius Thank you very much!! Sorry about that!

Comment: @Verbeia first comment :there is no specific reason for Divide[dogpopulation/cellsno, 9] I just typed it like that. second comment: Actually I would like to change the first rows and the second rows of each sub-matrix in my four dimensional table and according to a random number each time the first element of the first row in the first sub-matrix to become its value+ 1 and the same time the first element of the second row in the first sub-matrix to become its value -1. I want this to repeated for all the sub-matrices and all the elements in the first two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer has the "I did it at work without Mathematica to check my syntax" advisory on it**

@belisarius' answer works perfectly well, is more elegant, and is almost certainly more efficient than mine. But you might find an alternative that is easier for you to understand using the `ArrayFlatten` command ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)) or the `Join` command ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html)).

The first option assumes you want something like what the CODE in your question asks for, rather than what is stated in the text. You would then use something like:

```
nonisFunction[mylist_List,firstrowsub_?VectorQ, 
secondrowsub_?VectorQ,cutoff_Real]/; Length[Dimensions[mylist]]==4  :=
Table[
If[RandomReal[]>cutoff, 
    Join[{firstrowsub},{secondrowsub},Drop[mylist[[i,j]],2] ],
    mylist[[i,j]] ], 
    {i,Dimensions[mylist][[1]]}, {j,Dimensions[mylist][[2]]} ]
```

This effectively takes each submatrix and stitches it back together again, substiting each time the two rows to be substituted if the cutoff if exceeded, but leaving the submatrix alone if it is not.

If what you want is to increment and decrement the two rows (ie your text question rather than the code you provided), then a similar solution would simply need addition, not `Join`. Because `Plus` is `Listable`, it should thread the vector to be added over the rows of each submatrix.

```
nonisFunction[mylist_List,cutoff_Real]/; Length[Dimensions[mylist]]==4  :=
Table[
mylist[[i,j]] +
 If[RandomReal[]>cutoff, {1,-1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0} ],
    {i,Dimensions[mylist][[1]]}, {j,Dimensions[mylist][[2]]} ]
```

This table-based programming style is much more like the procedural programming style you are used to (quadruply nested `For` loops), but it is still more efficient, and I have come to the conclusion that you are more likely to understand the code.

**EDIT: additional material in response to noni's question in comments**
To run this code (taking the second example function above as the example for this process), you would first define the function by copying and pasting the above code into a Mathematica notebook. You would then define your input matrix and give it some name. e.g.

```
myinputmatrix = RandomInteger[{10,100},{4,4,4,4}];
```

And finally, call the `nonisFunction` with the appropriate arguments.

```
nonisFunction[myinputmatrix,0.4]
```

And if that doesn't help, I recommend the video tutorials http://www.wolfram.com/support/learn/get-started-with-mathematica/.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and forgive my silly question which is: how can I run this code? I think understand what it means but I cannot run it. I am new at Mathematica and I am struggling with everything... Thanks again

Comment: I checked your code and I think if a number is bigger that a random number then it changes all the elements in the first row with there values+1 and all the elements of the second row with its value -1. Can we do this for each element of the row and not for the whole row of a sub-matrix? I mean if a row in a submatrix is {2,3,4,5} and the second row {1,2,3,4} [if a random number is>0.4, {2+1,(if random>0.4, 3+1,3,),if(random>0.4,4+1,4),..} second row {2 (if the element in the first row is 3}, 3 (if second element in the first row is 4,3)....

Comment: This is possible, but I am at work and my lunch break is over (Australian time). So I can't help you until this evening at the earliest. And I think it would be better if you tried to work this on your own as an exercise. It is basically a merger of my two cases in the answer above. You would get the answer from someone the first time if you had taken the time to understand the problem you were trying to solve first (simulating populations in different locations) and then asking a well-posed question.

Comment: thank you very much I will try to do it by myself because I have to face a lot of problems like this one and I have to learn how to work with them, but can you also answer me any time you can?

Comment: I have done the code in the next code! Maybe is the worst code you have ever seen but is the only code that I manage to do that actually work. If you can help me to improve it I will appreciate it, Thanks

Comment: myFunction2[mylist_List, cutoff_Real] /; 
  Length[Dimensions[mylist]] == 4 := 
 Table[Transpose[
   Join[{If[RandomReal[] > cutoff, 
      Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, {2, 3}] + {-1, 1, 0}, 
      Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, {2, 3}]]}, {If[RandomReal[] > cutoff, 
      Drop[Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, 1], {}, {2}] + {-1, 1, 0}, 
      Drop[Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, 1], {}, {2}]]}, {If[
      RandomReal[] > cutoff, Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, 2] + {-1, 1, 0},
       Drop[mylist[[i, j]], {}, 2]]}]], {i, 
   Dimensions[mylist][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[mylist][[2]]}]

Comment: @noni: if it does what you want, and you can understand it, then it will do. I would suggest testing it with cutoff=0.0001 and cutoff=0.9999 to make sure it really is behaving as expected and you are assiging things to the right bits of the tensor. There are more elegant ways, but it is clear from your earlier postings that you are not familiar enough with Mathematica's more unusual constructs to follow these. For homework, read up on pure functions, Map, MapIndexed, Apply, FoldList and NestList. V

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will read those and I hope that I will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[mylist_List, rowPlus_Integer, rowMinus_Integer] := 
  Module[{temp = mylist},
    If[1 <= rowPlus <= Length@temp && 1 <= rowMinus <= Length@temp,
      If[ RandomChoice[{True, False}], 
        temp[[rowPlus]]++;
        temp[[rowMinus]]--];
      Return@temp,
    (*else*)
       Print@"Wrong row value"; Abort[]]]

a = IdentityMatrix[3]
a = f[a, 1, 2]
(*
{{2, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}
*)
a = IdentityMatrix[3]
a = f[a, 1, 2]
(*
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
*)
```

**Edit**

According to your new specifications:

```
f[mylist_List, rowPlus_Integer, rowMinus_Integer, cutoff_Real] :=
 Module[{temp = mylist},
  If[1 <= rowPlus <= Length@temp && 1 <= rowMinus <= Length@temp,
   MapIndexed[
    If[#1 > cutoff,
      temp[[rowPlus, First@#2]]++;
      temp[[rowMinus, First@#2]]--] &,
    RandomReal[1, Dimensions@temp[[2]]]];
   Return@temp,
   (*else*)
   Print@"Wrong row value"; Abort[]]]
```

Usage

```
a = IdentityMatrix[3];
a = f[a, 1, 2, .5]
(*
->{{2,1,0},{-1,0,0},{0,0,1}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but since I am new at mathematica, can you please explain me how this works?

Comment: @user if you focus your question on a piece of code, I could explain it. Mathematica is a pretty complicated beast to explain _all_ that is happening there. You should try to read the help docs first, and ?then_ ask whatever you don't understand.

Comment: what <=rowPlus<=Length@1&&1<=roeMinus<=Lenght@1, means and why you set up temp as 1?? I know maybe my question sounds silly but I am trying to learn mathematica by myself and I am struggling all the time :/

Comment: Can I ask you something else? Here, you have RandomChoice[True,False] and then temp[rowPlus]]++ temp[[rowMinus]]-- which means that every time the randomchoise is true it changes all the elements in each row.. it add one in the first row and substract 1 from the second row, in my case I want to check a if a random number is bigger than 0.4(for exaample) and if it is, I want this to add 1 in the first row and substruct one from the second but not for all the elements in a row the same time.. Can I do something like that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. And sorry for deleting my previous question!! I was trying to use your code for a four dimensional table and I couldn't. Can you please help me with that? Also, Can you please explain me what this code " If[1 <= rowPlus <= Length@temp && 1 <= rowMinus <= Length@temp, " means?

Comment: In four dimensional table I would like to use your code in each sub-matrix, for a table 3x3x3x3 for exaple I would like the changes that your code does in the first two rows of {_,_,1,_} and {_,_,2,_}